# Как добавить порядковый номер в загружаемые файлы на сервер?

Tags: php

Есть такой код сохранения фотографий в папку, сейчас все файлы называются с датой и далее рандомными цифрами. Мне нужно, чтобы в итоге в папку сохранились фото с названиями screen1, screen2 screen3 и т.д. Как мне в переменную $newname правильно вставить порядковый номер загружаемой фотографии?

Вот мой код:

```
$newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'/var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/uploads/'.$newname);
```

Comment: Из чего определяется порядковый номер? Откуда он берется, он порядковый по чему?

Answer (score 0):

1. Посчитать сколько файлов в папке

   ```
    $directory = "/dir";
    $files = scandir($directory);
    $num_files = count($files)-2);
   ```

   или

   ```
   $num = count(glob("/exact/path/to/files/*.jpg")) - 2;
   ```

   или

   ```
   $num = new FilesystemIterator('ПУТЬ_К_ДИРЕКТОРИИ', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
   ```

   и т.д.
2. Добавить "номер + 1"  к новому имени

Comment: В папке всегда 14 фото, нужно просто изменить название файлов так, как описал выше. Без проверок. "Добавить "номер + 1" к новому имени", вот именно на этом и загвоздка. Не могу найти как это сделать

Comment: Вопрос был "Как добавить порядковый номер в загружаемые файлы" и описание " нужно, чтобы в итоге в папку сохранились фото с названиями screen1, screen2 screen3" ........ ничего про "изменить наименования у уже имеющихся" нет

Comment: не нужно изменить существующие. Нужно в переменной newname изменить так, чтобы сохранялось screen1, screen2 screen3 в итоге

Comment: В чём проблема вписать вместо текущего наименования другое - без понятия........Подождём гадалку с хрустальным шаром

Comment: как вписать порядковый номер? загружаем 14 фото и как мне добавить к названию screen порядковые номера?

Comment: Если в цикле - бери номер из цикла

Comment: ладно подожду кто поможет

Answer (score 0):

```
    $counter = 0;
    print_r($screens_desc);
    foreach($screens_desc as $val)
    {
    $counter++;
    $newname = 'screen'.$counter.'.jpg'; 
move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'/var/www/www-root/data/www/site.ru/uploads/'.$newname);
    }
```

Comment: если что - в foreach есть синтаксис key => val, чтоб так не костылить........ Ну и в итоге как я и сказал - брать номер из цикла.....зачем надо было говорить после этого  "подожду кто поможет" не ясно  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]